# scroll to load more pagination swift

Tags: jquery, ios, swift, uitableview, pagination

My tableview when i reach the last cell it loads more cells, but the data it loads is the same data it already loaded from a url not new data for the new cells. Im not sure how to load more new items here is my code

```
func loadMoreItems() {


    loadItemsNow("entries")
}
  func loadItemsNow(listType:String){
  let kFeedParserExampleFeedSourceURL = "http://thestreetlede.com/feed/"
let myUrl = NSURL(string: kFeedParserExampleFeedSourceURL);

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            //self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        })

        return
    }
do {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
        self.parser = FeedParser(feedURL: kFeedParserExampleFeedSourceURL)
        self.parser?.delegate = self
        self.parser?.parse()


        let items = self.entries

        if self.fromIndex < items!.count {

            self.entries = items
            self.fromIndex = items!.count

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                //self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                //self.myTableView.reloadData()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    })
}

}

task.resume()
}
```

Has anyone implemented load more for tableview that can help? or push me in the right direction?

Comment: your data is loaded from a server, this server has any parameter to request some pagination data?

Comment: @ReinierMelian i don't believe so I'm getting the data from a rss feed. (thestreetlede.com/feed/)

Comment: OK, I try to check that, and try to help